# Pop Up in perl that goes away automatically after pause

Tags: perl, tk-toolkit

I'm writing a script to assist people who'll scan a barcode and get a response to keep or dispose the scanned sample. I want to have a message, similar to tk's messagebox or Win32::MsgBox but one that requires no user interaction to go away after three seconds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My thought was to create the messages in a child process, using `alarm` to kill the process after a delay. In Tk:

```
sub tmpMsgBox {
    my ($message,$delay) = @_;
    if (fork() == 0) {
        my $topWin = MainWindow->new;
        my $label = $topWin->Label();
        my $ok = $topWin->Button();
        $label->pack(-side => 'top');
        $ok->pack(-side => 'bottom');
        $label->configure(-text => $message);
        $ok->configure(-text => 'Ok', -command => sub {exit});

        $SIG{ALRM} = sub {exit};
        alarm $delay || 1;
        $topWin->MainLoop;
    }
}

for (3..10) {
    tmpMsgBox("This window will disappear in $_ seconds", $_);
}
```

I don't think Tk plays nicely with `fork`, though, so this idea probably won't work so well if you are also using `Tk` in your main process.

Answer (score 1):

[Desktop::Notify](http://p3rl.org/Desktop%3a%3aNotify) is the standard-compliant interface to the desktop's passive notification pop-ups.

```
perl -MDesktop::Notify -e'
    Desktop::Notify
        ->new
        ->create(
             body => q{why hello there},
             timeout => 3000
        )->show'
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is to send a destroy message to the window after your timeout (remembering to cancel the sending of the message if the user does choose something!) Tk's certainly capable of doing this.

```
# Make the timeout something like this...
$id = $widget->after(3000, sub {
    $widget->destroy;
});

# To cancel, just do...
$id->cancel;
```

You also need to make sure that you don't block when the widget is forced to go away, of course. This also prevents trouble if someone kills the widget by other means too, so it's a double-bonus.